# How to extract key size in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, pki

I'm trying to get the key size from a PEM-encoded certificate.

I've tried to extract it using node-forge (https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-forge), converting it first to a forge certificate and then trying to get the key size from that.

However, I cant find the right information in the forge certificate.

There is this info in the forge certificate under public key, and I think I should be able to get the information from the modulus 'n'

```
   { n: BigInteger { data: [Array], t: 74, s: 0 },
     e: BigInteger { data: [Array], t: 1, s: 0 },
     encrypt: [Function],
     verify: [Function] },
```

Here, the array for 'n' is

```
   BigInteger {
     data:
      [ 108702707,
        223366147,
        1633698,
        222104385,
        2057385,
        196952745,
        204102614,
        1342314,
        215447298,
        167299729,
        234087419,
        218888278,
        143261467,
        196197892,
        83562517,
        50733325,
        114027487,
        90758946,
        9956532,
        60800276,
        8677133,
        7005374,
        254551822,
        214728639,
        42558032,
        110792918,
        136202203,
        78922972,
        40753235,
        245284543,
        194070574,
        248422593,
        5163396,
        151359098,
        77422943,
        72471134,
        181405400,
        207346591,
        185707006,
        185418315,
        263158064,
        111864582,
        186113288,
        54738616,
        138771291,
        249640899,
        232181943,
        117496275,
        231520296,
        184509360,
        179085501,
        215072100,
        85449772,
        136664237,
        71259060,
        139830485,
        264798471,
        266417322,
        142764588,
        177236257,
        17830318,
        9879037,
        168589759,
        121974085,
        54883138,
        87144585,
        7724711,
        192243183,
        194739694,
        159581652,
        122617175,
        91020203,
        117134207,
        13 ],
     t: 74,
     s: 0 },
```

Can I get the key size from this array? Or is there another easier way to get the keySize from a PEM-encoded certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the approach below should work, since *n* is used as the modulus for the public and private keys, its length in bits is the key length too.

So if (as you say) we can get the size of *n* in bits we have the key length.

The public key is stored as a [big-integer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-integer), so we can call the [bitLength()](https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-integer#bitlength) function.

The code below is working for me:

```
const forge = require('node-forge');
const fs = require('fs');

function getCertificatePublicKeyBitLength(pemFile) {
    const certificate = forge.pki.certificateFromPem(fs.readFileSync(pemFile));
    return certificate.publicKey.n.bitLength();
}

console.log("Bit length: ", getCertificatePublicKeyBitLength("cert.pem"));
```

Comment: forge doesn't manage ECDSA keys. How to get these keys sizes ?

Comment: Not sure how to get ECDSA key size, certainly I don't believe it's possible with node-forge.

Comment: It's not. Sadly in my situation I can't use openSSL or the X509 classe from crypto. I've been looking for a way to proceed with pki.js but haven't found so far.